# how to determine point anomalies given window anomalies?

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been trying to determine how to detect point-anomalies given window-anomalies.

In more detail, I know for each 30-day window whether it contains an anomaly. For example, window 1 starts at 1/1/2009, window 2 at 1/2/2009, and so on.

Now I'm trying to use this knowledge to determine which dates these anomalies lie. If I have an anomaly on dates 1/5/2009 to 1/8/2009, my window will raise a signal for windows from a window with a last day of 1/8/2009 to a window starting on 1/5/2009.

I just don't see how I can find the exact intervals where there are anomalies using windows. Is there an approximation method that anyone can come up with? Feel free to include some code in Python if you'd like.

Thanks!

Comment: This question doesn't really seem to fit the "why doesn't this work" mantra of the site. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

> I just don't see how I can find the exact intervals where there are anomalies using windows.

You can't. How do you know there aren't two anomalies?

> Is there an approximation method that anyone can come up with?

For each interval of windows where there is continuously an anomaly detected, assume that there is an anomaly lasting from the last day of the first window to the first day of the last window.